# Ubuntu E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, libc

I am recieving the following error when attempting to install libc6:i386.

Here is the following error:

```
root@zeus-desktop:/home/zeus# sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu10).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-112-generic/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
Package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
Package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
 Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                        No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.112.118); however:
 Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                dpkg:            dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic:
```

linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic depends on linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic is not configured yet.

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
```

dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.13.0.32.52); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

My overall attempt is to install android-studio.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error may be here:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

You should try fixing that first.

Comment: Thank you! I removed a modification from the /etc/default/grub file 
on the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 
and it's working now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try running this

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then retry the install

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working, it brings the same error.